# How to tell C# SslStream AuthenticateAsServer to send a Certificate Trust List (CTL)

Tags: c#, ssl, client-certificates

I am trying to build my own secure (non-http) server using C#. Of course, I'm using the SslStream and AuthenticateAsServer. This works like a champ, except for I can't figure out how to make the server send a Certificate Trust List (CTL) to the client as part of the Client Certificate Request.

I see the LocalCertificateSelectionCallback, but that only seems applicable for AuthenticateAsClient since the AcceptedIssuers list is passed into the call back rather than you being able to specify it somehow.

I see how to set the CTL in IIS, but not in C# code. I'm working with raw sockets (with TLS encryption) so I can't just use IIS to host this service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out:

create a DWORD Value under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL
called "SendTrustedIssuerList" and set to "1"